# For NLP, is GPT-3 better than RoBERTa?

Tags: nlp, bert, transformer, gpt

I am learning deep learning and I want to get into NLP. I have done LSTM, and now I am learning about vectorisation and transformers. Can you please tell me, which algorithm is more effective and accurate?

Comment: Welcome to DataScience StackExchange. Please make your question more clear. NLP is a very broad field of ML, and different models must be used for different tasks. GPT-3 and RoBERTa, specifically, have been created for different reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are meant for different purposes and they are hardly comparable.

RoBERTa is meant for text classification and tagging tasks. The idea is that you take a pretrained RoBERTa model and finetune it on your (potentially small) classification or tagging dataset. Some examples of tasks where RoBERTa is useful are sentiment classification, part-of-speech (POS) tagging and named entity recognition (NER).

GPT-3 is meant for text generation tasks. Its paradigm is very different, normally referred to as "priming". You basically take GPT-3, give it some text as context and let it generate more text. The context should give GPT-3 the "pattern" of what it must generate. You don't finetune it, just give it some example of acceptable text generation pattern and then let it generate more alike.

Comment: It is now possible to finetune GPT3 models using the publicly available OpenAI API.